# How to use regular expression in some part of string in java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to use regex in some part of string in java,

In below string, only `emp-id-<dynamic empID>` and `project` remain same for all the string.

```
Case1:  project/emp-id1545/ID-JHKDKHENNDHJSJ

Case 2: project/**dep**/emp-id8545/ID-GHFRDEEDE
```

I’ve scenario sometime string come with `dep`, `temp`, or no value like `Case 1` after `project`.

How to filter only  `emp-id-<dynamic empID>` from the above string, to work with case 1 and case 2?

Comment: What have you attempted? Please show your code.

Comment: Is `CaseX` also part of your data? Does your data contain only one line or many lines?

Comment: Nope! Only the  project/emp-id1545/ID-JHKDKHENNDHJSJ and project/dep/emp-id8545/ID-GHFRDEEDE

Comment: Is  `project/emp-id1545/ID-JHKDKHENNDHJSJ project/dep/emp-id8545/ID-GHFRDEEDE` one string or two strings? I am asking since I don't know if I can use `^project` since `^` by default it will represent start of string, not start of line, so if there is some `project/emp-id...` at start of second line `^` will prevent us from finding it.

Comment: Thanks! its two different string, i mentioned two case to explain i may get the string contains with project/ and without project/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways you can accomplish this task

### Regex

The pattern

```
"emp-id\\d+"
```

should achieve what you're wanting for both cases.  The pattern matches "emp-id" plus 1 or more digits (`\\d+`).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String case1 = "project/emp-id1545/ID-JHKDKHENNDHJSJ";
    String case2 = "project/**dep**/emp-id8545/ID-GHFRDEEDE";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("emp-id\\d+").matcher(case1);
    // Changed from while to if cause we're only going to get the first match
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }

    matcher = Pattern.compile("emp-id\\d+").matcher(case2);
    // Changed from while to if cause we're only going to get the first match
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Results:

```
emp-id1545
emp-id8545
```

### Java 8

Given that your data indicates that the character "/" is a delimiter.  You can also use `String.split()` and `Stream.filter()` (Java 8) to find your String.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String case1 = "project/emp-id1545/ID-JHKDKHENNDHJSJ";
    String case2 = "project/**dep**/emp-id8545/ID-GHFRDEEDE";

    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(case1.split("/")).filter(s -> s.startsWith("emp-id")).findFirst().get());
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(case2.split("/")).filter(s -> s.startsWith("emp-id")).findFirst().get());
}
```

Results:

```
emp-id1545
emp-id8545
```

### Non Regex or Java 8

Still using "/" delimiter and "emp-id" you can use `String.indexOf()` and `String.substring()` to extract the String you're looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String case1 = "project/emp-id1545/ID-JHKDKHENNDHJSJ";
    String case2 = "project/**dep**/emp-id8545/ID-GHFRDEEDE";

    int index = case1.indexOf("emp-id");
    System.out.println(case1.substring(index, case1.indexOf("/", index)));

    index = case2.indexOf("emp-id");
    System.out.println(case2.substring(index, case2.indexOf("/", index)));
}
```

Results:

```
emp-id1545
emp-id8545
```